# Matlab: Graphing Multiple Vertical Bar Plots

Tags: matlab, for-loop, dataset, bar-chart

In my plot, I'm trying to display the average delay time from 6 airports for each of the 5 dates.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
F = dataset('xlsfile','Lab2_Delta');

DATES = {'11/26/2013','11/27/2013','11/28/20113','11/29/2013','11/30/2013'};
ORIGINS = {'CVG','ORD','ATL','LAX','MIA','DFW'};

for Index = 1:6
    for Index2 = 1:5
        Origin_Index = find(strcmp(F.Origin,ORIGINS(Index)));
        Date_Index = find(strcmp(F.Date,DATES(Index2)));
        Temps(Index2,Index) = mean(F.Delay(Date_Index));
    end
end

bar(1:5,Temps(:,Index)); hold on;

legend('CVG','ORD','ATL','LAX','MIA','DFW');
set(gca,'XTick',1:length(DATES));
set(gca,'XTickLabel',DATES);
ylabel('Mean Delay Times'); title('Delay Times Around Thanksgiving');
```

The plot that is displayed only shows the bars for one airport (CVG). How do I go about displaying the other cities?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data that we can try out?

Comment: @darthbith     

Is there a way to upload the dataset that I'm working with?

Comment: You can upload it to any filesharing service... Dropbox, or Skydrive etc.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D93C61347F978474%21194

here's a link to the data I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can construct a matrix `Y` with a row for each date, and a column for each airport, then `bar(1:5,Y)` should do the trick.

```
dates=1:5
delayCVG=rand(1,5);
delayMIA=rand(1,5)+1;
delayATL=rand(1,5)+2;
delayLAX=rand(1,5)+3;
delayDFW=rand(1,5)+4;
delayORD=rand(1,5)+5;

delay=[delayCVG' delayMIA' delayATL' delayLAX' delayDFW' delayORD'];

bar(dates,delay)
```

[image]